# Regex to replace a symbol & within quotes C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace '&' inside quotes.

#### Input

```
"I & my friends are stuck here", & we can't resolve
```

#### Output

```
"I and my friends are stuck here", & we can't resolve
```

Replace '&' by 'and' and only inside quotes, could you please help?

Comment: wow i didnt know there is such an easy way to get others to write regexes for you! Nice

Answer (score 0):

By far the quickest way is to  use the `\G` construct and do it with a single regex.

***C# code***

```
var str =
    "\"I & my friends are stuck here & we can't get up\", & we can't resolve\n" +
    "=> \"I and my friends are stuck here and we can't get up\", & we can't resolve\n";
var rx = @"((?:""(?=[^""]*"")|(?<!""|^)\G)[^""&]*)(?:(&)|(""))";
var res = Regex.Replace(str, rx, m =>
        // Replace the ampersands  inside double quotes with 'and'
        m.Groups[1].Value + (m.Groups[2].Value.Length > 0 ? "and" : m.Groups[3].Value));
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

***Output***

```
"I and my friends are stuck here and we can't get up", & we can't resolve
=> "I and my friends are stuck here and we can't get up", & we can't resolve
```

***Regex***  `((?:"(?=[^"]*")|(?<!"|^)\G)[^"&]*)(?:(&)|("))`

https://regex101.com/r/db8VkQ/1

***Explained***

```
 (                          # (1 start), Preamble

      (?:                        # Block
           "                          # Begin of quote
           (?= [^"]* " )              # One-time check for close quote
        |                           # or,
           (?<! " | ^ )               # If not a quote behind or BOS
           \G                         # Start match where last left off
      )
      [^"&]*                     # Many non-quote, non-ampersand
 )                          # (1 end)

 (?:                        # Body
      ( & )                      # (2), Ampersand, replace with 'and'
   |                           # or,
      ( " )                      # (3), End of quote, just put back "
 )
```

***Benchmark***

```
Regex1:   ((?:"(?=[^"]*")|(?<!"|^)\G)[^"&]*)(?:(&)|("))
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   10
Elapsed Time:    2.21 s,   2209.03 ms,   2209035 µs
Matches per sec:   226,343
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Regex.Replace(s, "\"[^\"]*\"", m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\B&\B", "and"))
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/nnDoih):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "\"I & my friends are stuck here\", & we can't resolve";
        Console.WriteLine(
            Regex.Replace(s, "\"[^\"]*\"", m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\B&\B", "and"))
        );
    }
}
```

Output: `"I and my friends are stuck here", & we can't resolve`